# How to change validation of wcmp vendor registration form password field(wordpress)

Tags: validation, passwords, registration, vendor

I need to edit password validation of wcmp vendor registration form.

Answer (score 1):

I know the reply is too late and you might have already found a solution.
However, for others out there, in order to remove the password validation for WCMp vendor registration form, add this to your functions.php in your custom/child theme.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_wc_password_strength_meterscript');
function remove_wc_password_strength_meterscript() {
    wp_dequeue_script('wc-password-strength-meter');
}
```